# How to create an Android Calendar event that ends X days from today

Tags: java, android, android-intent, calendar, android-activity

I am working on an android app that has a follow-up feature.

People will be able to put in some information including a description and the number of days in the future they want this event to start (IE 1 day, 10 days, 20 days) and then click the create button to create it.

The problem I am having is that I want the date to start X number of days in the future where X is the number of days in the future where it would start(an int passed in of days, IE 1 day, 10 days).

Here is my code:

```
//Create Calendar event
public void CreateEvent(){
    //Variables title, location, description, and days_from_now are all defined elsewhere
    Calendar mycal = Calendar.getInstance();

    Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
    calIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");

    //Put information in
    calIntent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, title); 
    calIntent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location); 
    calIntent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, description);

    **//Increment the date by X days
    mycal.add(mycal.DATE, days_from_now );

    //Start and end time
    long startTime = mycal.getTimeInMillis(); //Convert to milliseconds
    long endTime = startTime+900000; //15 minutes

    //Put the calculated start and end time into the calIntent Intent
    calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startTime);
    calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime);**

    startActivity(calIntent); 

}
```

Finally got it working! The bolded code is what was missing. Thanks for the ideas guys as they led me to the right code!

Comment: Instead of `mycal.roll(...)` you should use: `mycal.add(...)`.

Comment: I changed it to mycal.add() and it sadly did not seem to change much :(. Still not creating the event X days in the future. The code only creates an event this very minute, as opposed to X days in the future where X is the input response from the user, an unknown variable that will be defined via an editText field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple code:

```
public void addEvent(long calendarID, String title, long startEvent,
            long endEvent, int reminder, String description, long createDate) {
        try {
            System.out.println("add event to calendar");
            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Events.DTSTART, startEvent);
            values.put(Events.DTEND, endEvent);
            values.put(Events.TITLE, title);
            values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
            values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendarID);
            values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTimeZone().getID());
            System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID());
            Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
            long eventId = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            setReminder(cr, eventId, reminder);             
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setReminder(ContentResolver cr, long eventID, int reminder) {
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Reminders.MINUTES, reminder / 60000);
            values.put(Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventID);
            values.put(Reminders.METHOD, Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
            Uri uri = cr.insert(Reminders.CONTENT_URI, values);
            Cursor c = Reminders.query(cr, eventID,
                    new String[] { Reminders.MINUTES });
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                System.out.println("calendar"
                        + c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Reminders.MINUTES)));
            }
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I'm not quite sure this is what I'm going for. In theory, what I am looking for is a way to write code to create a calendar event that will have 1 main input parameter, days. Say the user chooses 5 days. What the code will do is create an event 5 days in the future (and make it last an hour). The days chosen will be from an edit text response box and parsed in as an integer. Is it possible for me to take said int X (whole number,  like 4 days) and make code that will create an event that starts those X number of days from now?

Comment: @Silmarilos ,you want to create an event that's just start in X days, and will last one hour?

Comment: Originally, something different, but after narrowing down my question, I realized what I am actually asking is how to start an event X days in the future. Figured that out from just playing around with different options

Comment: @Silmarilos As far as I understand you, then, using my example, you need to specify the amount startEvent as current date + X days (milliseconds), and endEvent - startEvent amount and duration of event (one hour for example). I understand you correctly?